# How to make Network alive but speed low, slow for upload, download?

Tags: networking, tcp, internet, udp, broadcast

I have own application written (Python, Java) which does upload/download for streaming.

Now in my local office network and home network setup i can't simulate slow/low latency network (as a result i have many issues when i am using with live users)

How do i tell my linux box that network interface eth0 is slow 
(such as lot of hops and ping reply is slow, speed like 3G simulated, without having the real thing)

with that kind of network setup, i want to have some unit testing (considering i have random users, and random users low networking speed internet), before production release.

***EDIT:***

http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem

```
tc qdisc add dev lo root handle 1:0 netem delay 5sec
```

Comment: Do you want to slow the network for the whole system, or for one application in particular?

Comment: @Gilles: slow the network for whole system, so that if my application depends on other third party library they also suffer the same simulation

Comment: I don't understand your comment: if you limit for one application, it's irrelevant which part of your application is third-party libraries and which part is your own code.

Comment: @Gilles: i mean for whole system.

Comment: I have found this solution and it WORKS - http://superuser.com/a/223975/82524